# How can I reply to someone's comment on a pull request on Github?

Tags: github, pull-request

Sorry if the question is trivial, but I couldn't find an answer.

I sent a pull request to a project. Someone commented something about it.

What would be the correct way to reply to his/her comment? I can simply add a comment of my own to the page. But is this the right way? Will he/she be 'notified' (if this even exists in Github)?

Comment: This has been a [long-standing feature request](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/169) in GitHub. It's 2024 and there are threaded comment replies for PR comments made in a file diff, but if you want to reply to a comment on the PR itself, you still have to add a new comment and (optionally) quote the text you are commenting on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add a comment of your own to the page. If their comment is in the diff (i.e. the "Files changed" tab), you can respond inline next to their original comment.

If you mention them by name (using `@username`), they should also get a notification telling them that someone has mentioned them.

Comment: I see. Is it cool to mention (@) the guy I'm responding to if the discussion is mostly between the two of us anyway? Because I'd like him to know I've fixed the PR so he can look at it again. If I don't use @, will he know about this only when deciding to browse to the PR?

Comment: I don't see any harm in mentioning him specifically. Whether he gets notified when you update the pull request depends on his notification settings. This is true for mentions also, but I would imagine that most people tend to leave that setting turned on.

Comment: In conversations over PRs, I usually don't see use of @. So I'd like to use it to get a response sooner, but don't want to seem rude (again excuse me for the beginner question). So in your opinion using @ after updating a PR to notify the collaborator is fine?

Comment: Where I work now, and where I've worked in the past, we've used the `@` mention to get someone's attention when a further action is needed on a pull request. This sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: BTW I'm talking open open source projects, if this matters. Also, what is your opinion about 'pinging' someone with @ after a while the PR didn't get attention from a collaborator?

Comment: It's hard to judge as each person may respond differently. Each project tends to have a way of working with pull requests, so you will have to go through whatever that is. Ultimately though, if the owner of an open source project doesn't merge a pull request quickly, there's not much you can do apart from forking the project and maintaining the fork yourself.

Comment: Where is "their original comment"?